# How to update tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column code to tf 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I came across a Gaussian Kernel classifier tutorial in Python that utilizes tensorflow. In part of the tutorial,  `tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column` is referenced. However, as far as I know,  `tf.contrib` is deprecated.

How can I change the statement to work in `tensorflow 2.0` ?

I tried using  `tf_slim` and  `tf.keras`, but I was unable to find the equivalent statements. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you find answer for this problem? having the same issue!

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? I am having the same. It would be brilliant to share your solution if you found it. Thanks!